# Need to deserialize a nested json array to server side array

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, json.net

I have an array nested in an object in a JSON string which I need deserialized at the server:

```
var orderStatus = {"auth": "xxxx", "resourceType": "order.status", "idSet": "2980", "lifecycleEvent": "modified", "objects": { "orders": [ { "id": "2980", "statusId": "6" } ] }
```

I use Robert Koritnik's plugin like this:

```
$.ajax({url: "receiveJson", type: "POST", data: $.toDictionary(orderStatus) });
```

My .net class file is:

```
public class orders
{ 
public string Id { get; set; }
public string statusId { get; set; }
}

public class objects
{
public orders orders { get; set; }
}

public class OrderStatus
{
public string clientName { get; set; }
public string source { get; set; }
public string auth { get; set; }
public string resourceType { get; set; }
public string idSet { get; set; }
public string lifecycleEvent { get; set; }

public objects objects { get; set; }

}
```

my controller code is:

```
public JsonResult receiveJson(OrderStatus orderStatus)
```

So the orders object is the array. It works up to creating orders as an object but id and status id in the orders object are null.

I have no control over the JSON I will receive, it has to be in this format.

I am new to JSON and .NET MVC. Don't know how to specify server side orders object as an array.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by slightly amending my server side classes:

```
    public class order
{        
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string statusId { get; set; }
}

public class objects
{
    public List<order> orders { get; set; }
}

public class OrderStatus
{
    public string clientName { get; set; }
    public string source { get; set; }
    public string auth { get; set; }
    public string resourceType { get; set; }
    public string idSet { get; set; }
    public string lifecycleEvent { get; set; }

    public objects objects { get; set; }

}
```

So the "orders" class has been changed to "order". "objects.orders" property is amended to be a list.

Now the jsondata is deserialized all the way down.